# Unexpected indent while doing recursion from inside the for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, recursion, machine-learning

I am running this code in python. I want to call the recursive_split function from inside the for loop. But the python shows unexpected indent error. Where am i going wrong?

```
res = {}
def recursive_split(X,y,recursive_count) :
    recursive_count = recursive_count+1
    if(recursive_count>depth):
        return res
    selected_attr = select_attribute(X,y)

    sets = partition(X.iloc[:,selected_attr])
    for key, value in sets.items() :
        print(str(key) + " " + str(value))
        y_subset = y.take(value, axis=0)
        X_subset = X.take(value, axis=0)
        res["x_%d = %d" % (selected_attr, key)] = 
        recursive_split(X_subset, y_subset,recursive_count)

    return res

recursive_count = 0
dict_tree = recursive_split(X_train,y_train,recursive_count)
```

the error message that i get is:

```
File "test.py", line 116
    res["x_%d = %d" % (selected_attr, key)]=recursive_split(X_subset, 
y_subset,recursive_count)
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: Please provide the full error with traceback. We need to know at least which line contains the error.

Comment: While you're at it make sure your editor didn't mix tabs and spaces somewhere.

Comment: Try replacing all tabs with spaces or vice versa.

Comment: Resolved. Actually the X_subset line had 8 spaces instead of 2 tabs. Came to know about that when i selected the entire code. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

the error might have to do with the fact that this line of code is split into two lines

```
res["x_%d = %d" % (selected_attr, key)] = 
recursive_split(X_subset, y_subset,recursive_count)
```

Try writing it in one line, and make sure there are no tabs.

And check it's syntax by compiling the file:

```
python -m py_compile file.py
```

Comment: the line is not actually split. It's written on a single line. The stackoverflow editior didn't had space so has to write it in 2 lines

Comment: This would cause a different error.